# how can I fix ManyToManyDescriptor from a lesson class model - view?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I am trying to build a single course platorm where I will only hold lessons units materials where only people with membership will be able to see it , however when I try to do retrieve `Lesson.course_allowed_mem_types.all()` I got the following error `'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'` , how can I fix this simple error?

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
  content_title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  content_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx')
  link = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  allowed_memberships = models.ManyToManyField(Membership)
​
  def __str__(self):
    return self.content_title
```

views

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(bootCamp, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['lessons'] = Lesson.objects.all()
        user_membership = UserMembership.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).first()
        user_membership_type = user_membership.membership.membership_type
        course_allowed_mem_types = Lesson.allowed_memberships.all()
        context['course_allowed_mem_types'] = course_allowed_mem_types
        return context
```

Comment: [`QuerySet.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) method might be interesting for your use case. You can retrieve ids of all allowed memberships of all lessons with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can query many-to-many related field only for model instance, not model class. It's not really clear what exactly is *"all concrete allowed membership objects for a Lesson class"* (`Lesson.allowed_memberships.all()`).

Is it *"all membership objects related to any of existing lesson objects"* or is it *"all membership objects that can be related to a lesson object"*?

Those are different queries, and `Lesson.allowed_memberships.all()` does not imply either, it's incorrect usage.

If you want the former, something like this could work

```
Membership.objects.filter(lesson__in=Lesson.objects.all())
```

(You already have this as `context['lessons']` so use that instead, just showing the idea)

Answer (score 0):

I think,
One lesson may have many memberships. so you are selecting all lessons with all memberships `Lesson.allowed_memberships.all()` .

Try selecting a single lesson then retrieve associated members

`lesson = Lessons.objects.filter(pk=1)`
`course_allowed_mem_types = lesson.allowed_memberships.all()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create custom list like type, it is always a good idea to inherit from `collections.abc.Iterable`. It provides common operations required to work on such container types.
You can't just call `.all()` on any object/type, that type definition actually has to have `all()` method defined in class or parent class.

e.g.

```
class ListLike:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def all(self):
        return some_iterator
```